# How to acess Image on a server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a Web application, 
I have its two Modules,both modules are separate solutions(ie projects):
1: Application
2: SiteSetup

Sitesetup module is a separate project, I am saving images for logo and banner in this project,the database of both modules is same and i am storing image name in database and file is physically saving on disk,
I want to display the stored Logo and banner in my  Application,How can i achieve this?
Regards

Comment: You can fetch that logo from Database

Comment: Yes i can fetch it from database but file is physically stored on disk, and i want to display on application, from database i'll get the location of file which is offcourse of a separate project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store image path relative to web application root and use "~/images/logo.png" syntax, then correctly resolve it in web application. use Path.Combine(webAppPath,"images") to get directory for the ~/images.

Answer (score 0):

As the path to the image is stored in your database, then your **Controller** will need to make the path to the image available to your **View** somehow.

This can be done a number of ways:

- As a property on a **Model** or **ViewModel** *- the Model gets the path*
- By using the [`ViewBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) *- the Controller gets the path*

Then in the **View**, you can use the [`Url.Content("path_to_image")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) helper method to reference the image file in an `<img />` tag like so:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.LogoImagePath)" alt="Logo" />
```

---

Note that the image file itself must be accessible by the WebServer - that means the Identity the WebServer is using (i.e. the Application Pool) must have read-access to the image and it's location.